# python arrow library does not enforce format

Tags: python, datetime, validation

Trying to validate a datetime entered as string. It works if I use the 'format' that matches the string exactly, which is a desired behaviour

```
>>> a=arrow.get('2023-12-06 10:01:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>>
>>> a=arrow.get('Wednesday 2023-12-06 10:01:02','dddd YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>>
>>> a=arrow.get('Wed 2023-12-06 10:01:02','ddd YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

and if the string does not match the format then an exception is raised, which is also desired behaviour

```
>>> a=arrow.get('Wed 2023-12-06 10:01:02','dddd YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

raise ParserMatchError(arrow.parser.ParserMatchError: Failed to match 'dddd YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' when parsing 'Wed 2023-12-06 10:01:02'
```

but sometimes the string and the format does not match either and the object is parsed, like in all these cases below:

```
>>> a=arrow.get('Wednesday 2023-12-06 10:01:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>>
>>> a=arrow.get('Wed 2023-12-06 10:01:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>>
>>> a=arrow.get('Wed Wednesday 2023-12-06 10:01:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>> a=arrow.get('Wed Wednesday 23 2023-12-06 10:01:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
>>>
>>> a=arrow.get('Wed Wednesday 2024 2023-12-06 10:01:02','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

so I can not effectively validate that a datetime string is valid because with some formats there is not exception raised.

An exception should be raised on all cases where the format is not exactly matching the datetime value that one would like to validate.

Is there any way to enforce the format to validate the datetime entered by the user?

Comment: Because the formatted substring is contained within the string, it does not throw an exception. It will only throw an exception if it fails to find the formatted substring.

Comment: txs, I figured but is there a way to circumvent that behavior and make the library enforce the format?